# vuex error - do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I need help.

I am using Quasar 2 (Vue 3 framework).

Why does `state.authorization = data.data.data.authorization;` in mutation returns "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers" error?

Store

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import { SessionStorage } from 'quasar'

import { LOGIN } from './actions'
import AuthService from './service'

const state = reactive({
  authorization: SessionStorage.getItem('authorization') || null
});

const getters = {
  getAuthorization: state => state.authorization
};

const actions = {
  // Login
  [LOGIN]: ({ commit }, data) => {
    return AuthService.login(data).then(
      data => {
        commit(LOGIN, { data: data });
        return Promise.resolve(data);
      },
      error => {
        commit(LOGIN_ERROR);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }
}

const mutations = {
  // Login
  [LOGIN]: (state, data) => {
    SessionStorage.set('authorization', data.data.data.authorization);
    state.authorization = data.data.data.authorization;
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.data.data.authorization;
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

Within .vue file

```
let data = {
  email: email.value,
  password: password.value
};

store.dispatch(LOGIN, data).then(...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you conclude that it's the code inside mutation that triggers a warning? `state` shouldn't be `reactive`, this is done by Vuex

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
If I comment "state.authorization = data.data.data.authorization;" then it works but I need to change the state.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
const state = {
  authorization: SessionStorage.getItem('authorization') || null
};
```

to

```
const state = () => ({
  authorization: SessionStorage.getItem('authorization') || null
});
```

fixed the problem.